# Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/cli-utils

Tags: ionic3

my existing working app today all of sudden throwing

```
{ Error: Cannot find module '@ionic/cli-utils'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (module.js:469:15)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:417:25)
    at Module.require (module.js:497:17)
    at require (internal/module.js:20:19)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/vskumar/Dropbox/OscIbcsBotsGit/angular2/osc_ionic_angular2/node_modules/ionic/dist/index.js:8:21)
    at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:438:3) code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND' }
```

any thing related to ionic like ionic -v etc throws the same error. please advise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try `npm install -g ionic@latest`